# pthread mutexes, thread synchronization using pthread_mutex_trylock()

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I've been working on getting a key value hash dictionary, and one of the things I need to do is rehash when the load factor reaches a threshold, so to make sure no other threads are accessing it I'm trying to bring it down to a single queue.

Will this successfully prevent more than one thread from being able to read/write to the resource at the same time, or is there something I'm missing.

Thanks!!

```
typedef struct {
  pthread_mutex_t mutex;
  pthread_cond_t cond;
  pthread_rwlock_t rw_lock;
} thread_conch;

typedef struct {
  thread_conch d_lock;
  size_t elements;
  size_t hash_size;
  struct kv_record **bucket;
} dictionary;

void init_conch(thread_conch *t_lock)
{
  pthread_mutex_init(&t_lock->mutex, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&t_lock->cond, NULL);
  pthread_rwlock_init(&t_lock->rw_lock, NULL);
}

void destroy_conch(thread_conch *t_lock)
{
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&t_lock->mutex);
  pthread_cond_destroy(&t_lock->cond);
  pthread_rwlock_destroy(&t_lock->rw_lock);
}

void hold_conch(thread_conch *t_lock)
{
  pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&t_lock->rw_lock);
  while (pthread_mutex_trylock(&t_lock->mutex) != 0)
    ;
}

void read_conch(thread_conch *t_lock)
{
  while (pthread_rwlock_tryrdlock(&t_lock->rw_lock) != 0)
    pthread_cond_wait(&t_lock->cond, &t_lock->mutex);

}
void release_conch(thread_conch *t_lock)
{
  pthread_rwlock_unlock(&t_lock->rw_lock);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&t_lock->mutex);
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&t_lock->cond);
}
```

Comment: I think that the condition variable here is unnecessary and a simple mutex should do the trick. You haven't posted the code of how you call hold_conch / release_conch from your threads and how they are created so it's hard to say if this will succeed. Like your Lord of the Flies reference.

Comment: On second thought, one simple mutex is not enough, since you would like to allow more than one reading thread at a time but not allow any reading threads when your writing thread is working. I'd suggest you search for the "Readers–writer lock" on the web.

Comment: I took your advice and incorporated read locks, while still using the mutex and conditional wait for read threads that try to read while the write is occurring, should this be ok? Essentially I want to make sure the resource is unavailable and any threads trying to access it get blocked while it's being written to. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, from what I understand, if you use a read write lock, you don't need the mutex or the conditional variable as the whole mechanism is already implemented for you. You call pthread_rwlock_rdlock from reader threads and pthread_rwlock_wrlock from the writer thread and that should take care of that, providing initialization is ok.